# table alignment when creating table using divs?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table which is created using Divs and as my columns grew its hard to recognize if it was a table or something else?

**What i want**

I want all columns in each row to be aligned to another irrespective of width?
Just like a normal table
[image]

**What I have**

```
<div class="tabularStructure">  
<div id="token1">
    <div class="cell">
         <label><bdi>${PredefinedSearch_Label}</bdi></label>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
         <select id="predefineSrch">
            <option value="default">(None)</option>
        </select>   
    </div>

    <div class="cell">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;
    </div>

</div>
```

```
       <div class="spacer">&nbsp; </div>

   <div class="tabularStructure">   
<div  id="token2">
    <div class="cell">
    <label><bdi>${Date_Label}</bdi></label>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <select id="date">
             <option value="default">(None)</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="cell" id="token3">
        <label><bdi>${DayRange_Label}</bdi></label>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <select id="dayRange">
             <option value="default">(None)</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="cell" id="token5">
        <label for="idFromDate"><bdi>${From_Label}</bdi></label>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <input type="text" id="idFromDate" name="toDate" class="date" />
    </div>

    <div class="cell" id="token4">
        <label for="idToDate"><bdi>${To_Label}</bdi></label>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <input type="text" id="idToDate" name="to" class="date" />
    </div>
        </div>
             </div>
```

**Check the fiddle for full code** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEHSB/)

Comment: Don't go as everyone says **DONT USE TABLES** :p Actually **YOU SHOULD USE TABLES FOR TABULAR DATA**, you don't have to use it for designing layouts You should not use `div` for tabular data, and use `div` for designing layout, now you see, it's a mess with div's here, it is better to use `table` for this particular example

Comment: Why not create your table using a `<table>`?

Comment: *What i want ... Just like a normal table*, then use one. ;)

Comment: Please use a table for your task. That is the reason tables are invented for. If you want to go with divs I suggest you use a framework as [Unsemantic](http://unsemantic.com/demo-responsive).

Comment: I was criticized the other day as i used table but when ido use div still get criticized

Comment: Normally I would concede that tables can be appropriate for laying out forms as they are a key (label)/value (field) pair. However, tables are clearly being used here for layout. If that table had a <thead /> element to contain table headings, what would they read?  I see no tabular relationship being expressed the way the elements are currently arranged.

Comment: @cimmanon Who said that there's a compulsion to use `thead`

Comment: @Mr.Alien I'm referring to a theoretical thead.  Not all tables *require* one, but the fact that there isn't one begs the question of *why?*  If the answer is because *these columns have nothing in common*, then its a pretty clear indication that you might be using a table for layout purposes.

Comment: @cimmanon I use what is comfortable :) My boss uses tables, and he is earning crores

Comment: @Mr.Alien If you're ok with using tables for layout purposes, that's your choice.  Just don't pretend there's tabular data involved in this particular instance, because there's not.  The W3C says you *shouldn't* do it and gives compelling reasons why not.  At the end of the day, if tables are the absolute 100% only way to do this, no one is going to run you out of town with a pitchfork.

Comment: @cimmanon I guess you are only one over here who says that this shouldn't be a table...

Comment: If you're going to use a table for layout, at least use the `role="presentation` attribute so screenreaders will not attempt to interpret the structure as a tabular data.